# Copy/Paste in gvim broken after creating personal vimrc

Tags: windows-7, vim, copy-paste, gvim

I'm using gvim on win 7. If I use the default installation copy/paste with Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v works fine. As soon I create a personal `_vimrc` file in my home folder I have to use the menu to paste something from the system clipboard into gvim. Ctrl+v is no longer working.

This is not dependant of the contents of the `_vimrc` file. It happens even if `_vimrc` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching I found that `:scriptnames` shows a list of all scripts that are excuted when gvim starts.

The short answer is: Don't start with an empty `_vimrc` if you are happy with your gvim configuration and just want to tweak the existing settings. Instead copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc` (or wherever gvim is installed on your machine) to your home folder and add your settings to the end of the file.

The long answer: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc` includes a number of usefull settings for windows. Part of this is the mapping for Ctrl+c, Ctr+v for copy paste. If you start with an empty `_vimrc` in your home folder this isn't included any more.

Comment: Thanks!   In particular, for Vim 8.0, the line to include Windows-like behaviour was:  source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim

Answer (score 3):

Add the two lines below at the end of your _vimrc

> source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim

"This line is copied from C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim_vimrc (If delte this line, copy/paste is broken)

> behave mswin

"This line is copied from C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim_vimrc (If delte this line, copy/paste is broken)

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question,(an answer has been accepted) it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation why it is better than the accepted answer or how the  solution works. If you feel this is an answer do these things and re-edit. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- [help] .Answering:[answer], again welcome to superuser.Thankyou